# How can I change the content of a single WebView (Android) depending on which button the user clicks (out of three) in one activity?

Tags: java, android, url, webview, onclick

Hi I am new to Android development and StackOverflow.

I have an Android WebView application in which a 'starter activity' (just intro text and a button to start main intent) starts my WebView activity, which loads a single URL (this is in the onCreate method).

In this main activity, I have three buttons, one of which opens the same URL in the current activity (effectively refreshing the page). The other two buttons I would like to open two different URLs in the same WebView activity, and I was wondering if/how this is possible.

Here is the main ReadWebpageAsyncTask.java activity code:

```
public class ReadWebpageAsyncTask extends Activity {

  private WebView browser;
  protected String urlStrOne = "url one";
  protected String urlNewCourses = "url two";
  protected String urlFutureCourses = "url three";


  @Override     
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_webpage_async_task);
  browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
  browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
  browser.loadUrl(urlStrOne);
  }


  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
  public void onClick(View view){
  browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
  browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
  browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
  browser.loadUrl(urlStrOne);
  }


  private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView browser, String urlStrOne) {
     browser.loadUrl(urlStrOne);
     return true;
  }
  }   

  @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(browser.canGoBack()) {
            browser.goBack();
        } else {
       // Let the system handle the back button
       super.onBackPressed();
        }
  }
  }
```

And the corresponding XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="left|right"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/readWebpage"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/soon"
    android:background="@+drawable/custom_button_one"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/load_page" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/exitapp01"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/soon"
    android:background="@+drawable/custom_button_one"
    android:onClick="exitButton"
    android:text="@string/exit_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/soon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/exitapp01"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/readWebpage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="comingSoon"
    android:text="@string/future_courses" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/WebView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/WebView01" >

</WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

P.S. Please excuse the terrible naming of everything, I wrote this a while back and haven't gotten around to changing it all.

To clarify, the main URL which is loaded first is the same as the button "readWebpage", and the other two URLs which I would like to be loaded on click are buttons "exitapp01" (what can I say, I am a noob) and "soon".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `OnClickListener`s to your buttons and switch the url depending on the case:

```
public class ReadWebpageAsyncTask extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private WebView browser;
    protected String urlStrOne = "url one";
    protected String urlNewCourses = "url two";
    protected String urlFutureCourses = "url three";
    Button reload, exit, soon;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_webpage_async_task);
        browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        browser.loadUrl(urlStrOne);

        reload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.readWebpage);
        exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exitapp01);
        soon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soon);

        reload.setOnClickListener(this);
        exit.setOnClickListener(this);
        soon.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public void onClick(View view){

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()) {

            case R.id.readWebpage:
                browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                browser.loadUrl(urlStrOne);
                break;
            case R.id.exitapp01:
                //Do whatever you want with this button
                break;
            case R.id.soon:
                //Do whatever you want with this button
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

And remove all the `android:onClick=""` from your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/readWebpage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exitapp01"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/soon"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply CarlosJimenez, I'm implementing your code now and have encountered an error of: 'The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (ReadWebpageAsyncTask)', not sure if I did something wrong or if I forgot to import something maybe?

Comment: Did you add this line in your class? `public class ReadWebpageAsyncTask extends Activity implements OnClickListener`

Comment: I tried that as Eclipse suggested this as well, and it caused a fatal exception at runtime when I tested on the Genymotion emulator.

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: 07-25 17:06:57.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1808): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Comment: That's a problem in your xml. You are giving too many references to the position of the buttons, remove some of the `toRightOf` and `toLeftOf` in your buttons and that will solve the problem.

Comment: Actually I just updated my answer, check it and that should solve the problem

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much :) wish I could 1up your solution, says I need more rep though :( will come back when I have it and 1up you.

Answer (score 0):

If The buttons are on Activity You have to set the OnClickListener on all the buttons and within the onClick() do like this:

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

```
    switch(view.getId()) {

     case R.id.[Your first button Id]:
       {
         //Functionality
        }
     case R.id.[Your Second button Id]:
       {
        //Functionality
       }
     case R.id.[Your first button Id]:
      {
       //Functionality
       }
```

//End Switch
}

//You also need To Write implements OnClickListener at the Class Definition Of Your activity